# Firebase swift dynamic link twice

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Im having a issue with Firebase and Dynamic Links.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool
```

is triggered more than once.
For example after using the dynamic link on the device - the app opens and "open url" is called. Then i delete the app, reinstall and the "open url" is triggered again with the dynamic link.

Any idea why this could be happening? 
Is maybe issue correlated with this similar problem on android?
[Firebase dynamic links handled twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652526/firebase-dynamic-links-handled-twice)

Comment: The same problem for me. Seems nobody take care about it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149078/about-behavior-of-dynamic-links