# About behavior of Dynamic Links

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Xcode version: 9.3.1

Firebase SDK version: 5.0.1

Firebase Component: Dynamic Links

Component version: 3.0.0

I implemented Dynamic links in project. I have a problem, I don't know the behavior that is true. Could you help me resolve it?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install App from App store.
2. Share a link for project.
3. Delete App on device.
4. Tap an link share at above (2)
5. Move to App store and install again app.
6. App receiver the content of link shared from Dynamic links.
7. Delete App on device.
8. Open App store and install again app, (Move to App store not via
   dynamic links).
9. App still receiver the content of link shared from Dynamic links.

The function

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *)options

it's alway return the link for share when i removed and install app again.

At step 9 : "App still receiver the content of link shared. " , In my opinion, i think that is wrong.

Let me know your opinion and If it's wrong , please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I temporarily resolved this problem but I not sure this is root core.
I used property "mathType" to check.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) FIRDLMatchType matchType;

FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url];
 if (dynamicLink) {
       if (dynamicLink.url && dynamicLink.matchType == FIRDLMatchTypeUnique) {
             // to check App install when tap an link shared.
       } 
       if (dynamicLink.url && dynamicLink.matchType == FIRDLMatchTypeWeak) {
             // to check App install via App store (not tap an link shared).
       } 
}
```